# Make a download button for each file in a folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that host some files on it, they are all in a `download` folder. I would like to know, if its possible to make an automation; each file have its dedicated button, and each button is like this `file.exe download`. 
Or I have to manually type every button ?
*Thanks!*

Comment: You can use `.forEach()` in Javascript to repeat making a button for each file.

Comment: How do you read files names in download folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .forEach() in Javascript to repeat making a button for each file.

Javascript

```js
var files = []; //array containing the file paths, e.g. "/download/file.exe"
files.forEach(file => {
    document.write(`<a href="${file}" download>
                        <button>Download ${file}</button>
                    </a>`)
})
```

If you want to make the button say "Download *What you call the file*" instead, you can make a separate array with the names:

```js
var files = []; //array containing the file paths, e.g. "/download/file.exe"

var filenames = []; //array containing the file names, e.g. "File.exe"

files.forEach((file, index) => {
    document.write(`<a href="${file}" download>
                        <button>Download ${filenames[index]}</button>
                    </a>`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you build web from php js you can simple put script foreach 
assume that you have array all file name in variabel

```
$data = array('download1.pdf', 'download2.pdf'); // example your array file 
<?php  $link = 'example.com/download'; ?> // your path download
<?php foreach($data as $download) { ?>
 <a href="<?= $link."/".$download ?>" _target='blank'?><?= $download ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```